# Locating resource in Jar

Tags: java, resources, path, jar, embedded-resource

I am having difficulty creating the image icon.  I want to package a jar and have the images available to be displayed in the gui.  Both of the following throw null pointer exceptions.  The path is a path directly to a package in my Eclipse project that contains the necessary images.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(
   "/TicTacToe/src/edu/luc/tictactoe/gui/resources/images/TicTacToeOIcon.png")
   .getPath());
```

and

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
   "/TicTacToe/src/edu/luc/tictactoe/gui/resources/images/TicTacToeOIcon.png"));
```

I can't see to be able to access the appropriate package.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `TicTacToeOIcon.png`  Are you sure about that `O`?  BTW 1) having a resource 8 levels deep seems to be asking for trouble (especially when the code is having trouble locating the resource).  2) That `src` part of the path sounds like an IDE enforced directory structure that should have vanished by build stage.  3) Forget the version that has `getPath()`.  The constructor would presume the `String` represents a `File` rather than an `URL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("edu/luc/tictactoe/gui/resources/images/TicTacToeOIcon.png");
```

Comment: (polite cough) In which version of the J2SE did they add an [`ImageIcon` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#constructor_summary) that accepts an `InputStream`?

Comment: It worked when I used getResource instead of getResourceAsStream

Comment: Andrew, you are right. I just copied from another source:-) thank you for the note!

Comment: Note that I don't get informed unless you start a comment with @Andrew.  I just jumped back into this thread to try and figure why the OP had started a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385588/using-an-image-panel-with-a-jar) along much the same lines. ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I did start a new thread because the questions are different.  I believe you also answered my second question.  But nontheless the two are two distinct questions.  They are similar but different.  Is there a preferred way to ask what I asked?  From my experience with SO if I ask both question in the same thread only on gets answered.  I made two threads for two questions and the were answered perfectly by StanislavL and yourself.

Comment: @MatthewKemnetz  Agreed.  It was when I went back to the other question that I noted the differences, and provided an answer rather than voting to close.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
JButton myButton =new JButton(“press me”);
myButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

EDIT:

Refer to this [discussion](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/122909) to know loading the image from executable Jar files

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for.  I know this already.  The creation of the ImageIcon is the problem.  How do I store the necessary pngs and access them with the code such that when I export the runnable jar I get the correct output?

Comment: I have edited the title and tags of the question to make it more clear.