# Using an Image Panel with a Jar

Tags: java, swing, jar

I am having trouble getting my ImagePanel to display when I pack it was a jar.  When I run the project from Eclipse it displays just fine.  here is the line that creates the ImagePanel:

```
ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(this.getClass().getClassLoader()
    .getResource("edu/luc/tictactoe/gui/resources/images/UIMM.png"));
frame.setContentPane(panel);
```

and here is the ImagePanel class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage img;

    public ImagePanel(URL url) {
        super(true);
        this.setToolTipText(url.getPath());
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File(url.getPath()));
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(
                img.getWidth(), img.getHeight()));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: unrelated to your current problem: (repetition of my comment to @trashgod in his answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960279/add-other-components-to-jframe-with-background) a) super(true) is redundant, panel is double-buffering by default b) even when covering everything, it might have transparent areas - so not calling super is complying to super's contract only if opaque == false. which it isn't by default and can be changed by client code at any time. So it's not really safe, and letting your IDE type one additional line is ... :-)

Comment: `g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);`  Since a `JPanel` is an `ImageObserver`, replace `null` with `this`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File(url.getPath()));  // REMOVE!
```

Try this instead..

```
img = ImageIO.read(url);
```

---

BTW - When things go wrong it would pay not to stumble blindly through what is happening.  Better to use a debugger and examine the actual values passed, or at least use `System.out.pritln()` as a sanity check.  E.G.

```
import java.net.URL;

class URLTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("jar:file:/C:/baz.jar!/COM/foo/Quux.class");
        System.out.println(url);
        System.out.println(url.getPath());
    }
}
```

### Output

```
jar:file:/C:/baz.jar!/COM/foo/Quux.class
file:/C:/baz.jar!/COM/foo/Quux.class
```

Now tell me.  Does the path even *look* like a file name/path?

***When in doubt.  Print out.***

Answer (score 0):

you need to make it into a jar, within the folder that you've made it in make a folder called "edu" in that a folder called "tictactoe" in that "gui" in that "resources" in that "images" and finaly in that, make a picture called "UIMM.png"

in other words, make the same folder structure with in the folder the jar in in.

I had the same problem as well 
p.s I think you are using a mac, if you are, bundle it with Jar Bundler app, it's the best bundler for a mac